# How can I change my birth date on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I entered my birthday incorrectly and I don't know how to change it.

Please show me the way, because everyone sees my profile and thinks I'm a little old.

Comment: because your birthday is important to recover your account security Facebook : attention please :  If you have your birthday, address, and phone number, you are making it easy for somebody to steal your identity.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your profile -> click on "Update Info" -> Click "Edit" on Basic Info and provide new date and Save it.

Answer (score 3):

To edit your date of birth:

1. Go to your timeline
2. Click the Update Info button (under your cover photo)
3. Find the Basic Info section and click Edit
4. Enter your real birthday in the Birthday field
5. Save your changes

There's a limit in a place around the number of times you can edit your birthday.

Comment: What to do now? facebook is not allowing to change birth date.. the fields are disabled